# PHP print from two tables where attribute from table A matches id in table B

Tags: php, html, echo

I am building a simple adress book website where you can enter information about a person and then enter information about adresses. You can then select where people lives using a drop down menu to update the building id attribute in the person to match the automaticly generated id in the building. What I can't figure out how to do print all info about all persons(this I can do) and then print the info about the building that matches each persons building id(this I have no idea how to do. Right now I am using a while loop to print each person. But I can't get the matching building to print.

Edit: also, thanks for all info I have gotten from this site in my learning of webbprograming

Comment: Could you give us some code to look at and maybe we could help from there?

Comment: search for `mysql inner join syntax` plenty of examples

Answer (score 0):

You could use `joins` in SQL to combine several tables in one query. Also you could use `GROUP BY`.

Just search for that and I think you will get a good tutorial in your language.

Here are some good links:

[SQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), [SQL GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Could use some code and table names to help define this example a little better, but regardless, you need to change your mysql query. In your database you need at least 1 matching row between your `persons` table and your `buildings` table. This way you can `JOIN` them together using the common row.

I will be using `id` as a placeholder for the common row in this example. Somethings like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM persons LEFT JOIN buildings ON(persons.id=buildings.id) WHERE persons.building_id = buildings.building_id
```

To get all the results from `persons` and `buildings` you will need a separate query. But, the query above should give you the results of the person's info where the `building_id` matches the `building_id` from `buildings`.